# How to add row and column to a dataframe of different length?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes of different length:

```
Headers <- data.frame(x = paste0("x", 1:4), y = 1:4)
Dataset <- data.frame(H = c(20, 10, 11, 8, 10), W = c(30, 20, 30, 10, 6)) 

Headers
   x y
1 x1 1
2 x2 2
3 x3 3
4 x4 4

Dataset
   H  W
1 20 30
2 10 20
3 11 30
4  8 10
5 10  6
```

I need to convert column 'x' from 'Headers' to header, and column 'y' to corresponding values, and then bind to 'Dataset':

```
H   W  x1  x2  x3  x4
20  30  1   2   3   4
10  20  1   2   3   4
11  30  1   2   3   4
 8  10  1   2   3   4
10   6  1   2  3    4
```

Here is the code which I tried:

```
 H <- t(Headers)
 Dataset <- cbind(H, Dataset)
 names(H)  <- NULL
 Dataset <- qpcR:::cbind.na(H, Dataset)
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpose 'y' and repeat to the desired number of rows. Set column names to 'x'.

```
cbind(Dataset, `colnames<-`(t(Headers$y)[rep(1, nrow(Dataset)), ], Headers$x))

   H  W x1 x2 x3 x4
1 20 30  1  2  3  4
2 10 20  1  2  3  4
3 11 30  1  2  3  4
4  8 10  1  2  3  4
5 10  6  1  2  3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)

cbind(Dataset, dcast(Headers, . ~ x, value.var = "y")[,-1])
```

Output:

```
   H  W x1 x2 x3 x4
1 20 30  1  2  3  4
2 10 20  1  2  3  4
3 11 30  1  2  3  4
4  8 10  1  2  3  4
5 10  6  1  2  3  4
```

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

Headers %>%
  rownames_to_column %>%
  spread(x, y) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(first(na.omit(.)))) %>%
  cbind(Dataset, .) %>% select(-rowname)
```

Output:

```
   H  W x1 x2 x3 x4
1 20 30  1  2  3  4
2 10 20  1  2  3  4
3 11 30  1  2  3  4
4  8 10  1  2  3  4
5 10  6  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a character vector,This is the error I am getting

Comment: Not sure what could be behind, I'm using your example. Perhaps you haven't changed dataframe names? I've edited now my answer using your newly added names, plus I've added another option with data.table, I think one of them should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go with basic R

```
cbind(Dataset,data.frame(matrix(rep(Headers$y,each=nrow(Dataset)),nrow=nrow(Dataset))))
```